# An existing connection is stopping me from sending an email with python

Tags: python, smtp

I have been trying to send an email with python but every time I try to run the code it fails, giving me an error message that an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I have followed several different youtube videos, copying the code letter for letter, and while it works in the videos I always get the same message. I honestly have no idea what to do.

This is the code with any sensitive data replaced

```
import smtplib

with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.ehlo()

    smtp.login('dummyemail@dummy.com', 'dummypassword')

    subject = 'test confirmed'
    body = 'Looks like it works'

    msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'

    smtp.sendmail('dummyemail@dummy.com', 'recievingemail@recieve.com', msg)
```

Here is the error that I recieve every time I try to run the program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 387, in getreply
    line = self.file.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mycomputer/Desktop/test folder/send Email/app.py", line 3, in <module>
    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 338, in connect
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 391, in getreply
    + str(e))
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I would greatly appreciate anyone who is able to tell me what I am doing wrong. At this point it feels like i'm just banging my head against a wall hoping for the code to magically start working.

Comment: By any chance, do you have two factor authentication enabled on the email you're making smtp connections with?

Comment: I have it disabled for the dummy email but not the recieving email. I also allowed less secure apps to have access to the dummy email.

Comment: Okay, how about the domain of the email. In the question it says `@dummy.com`. Is it actually a gmail email?

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is anything wrong with your code. I just ran it with my own dummy emails and it works.

Comment: It is a gmail account. I've been trying to run the program through my works internet, is it possible that a firewall or filter is shutting down the connection before it can do anything?

Comment: Potentially. It could also be due to the port you are making smtp connections with. My services use port 465.

Comment: I just tried using port 465 and that didn't work either. I'll have to try the code at home and see if it works there.